# MySQL select count(distinct id) is very slow

Tags: mysql, select, query-optimization, distinct-values

I have a MyISAM table with about 70 million records. When I do `select count(distinct id)` it takes about 80 seconds to get the query results. This table is a de-normalized table, that's why I need to get the unique count for id, and it has to be done dynamically. If I add a where clause, depending on the range I give, it takes a shorter time between 4 - 90 secs.

I'm wondering if there is any way I can optimize this to improve the query speed.

Comment: Do you have an index on column `id`?

Comment: can you show query? can you use `explain select......`?? what about the structure? PK, FK? index?, type of index??

Comment: Yes, I have index on id field, and index for fields in where clause, that's why when I use "where" depends on the range, the query is faster.
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tmp_rep_1018 | index | NULL          | cid  | 4       | NULL | 79146975 | Using index |

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS DISTINCT(id) FROM ...`, and after that execute query `SELECT FOUND_ROWS() AS Total` in order to fetch result.

Comment: I recommend you reading this blog post http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Comment: Forgot to say that we need to see table structure in order to provide you more precise answer.

Comment: It takes like 7 mins with sql_Calc_found_rows and what I need is figure out a better way to get a count number, thank you.